# An object was used after being disposed - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

[image]

Error: A **`xyz`** was used after being disposed.

Comment: Please, post your code so we're able to tell what's going on.

Comment: No screenshots of text please.  Paste the text enclosed with ``` on a line by itself both before and after the text.

Comment: Thanks, It's been fixed- yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was using the ChangeNotifierProvider() for the already created objects instead of ChangeNotifierProvider.value();